Ошибка при запуске скрипта в IDA
Пытался добавить трейсер в IDA, почему то выдает ошибку C:\Users\shipp\OneDrive\Desktop\IDA-EasyRe-main\easyRE.py: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль. Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:\IDA Pro v.8.3\python\3\ida_idaapi.py", line 577, in IDAPython_ExecScript exec(code, g) File "C:/Users/shipp/OneDrive/Desktop/IDA-EasyRe-main/easyRE.py", line 31, in <module> from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.
